# Как получить позицию строки в выдаче MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, сортировка

Выполняем запрос:
`SELECT id, name, rank FROM table ORDER BY rank DESC, id DESC`
Мне нужно получить позицию в этой выдаче строки с фиксированным id (например id=50). Как это сделать?

id - это первичный ключ.

rank - индекс, но не уникальный, то есть может быть хоть 100 записей с одинаковым значением rank

Comment: добавить счётчик `join (select set n := 0) t` и инкрементить его в селекте `select n := n + 1, остальные поля`

Comment: Я имел в виду как получить позицию строки с id=50 которая будет в этой выдаче не выполняя саму выборку. Если в таблице много записей, то это будет долго.

Comment: тогда сначала получите у этой записи значения тех полей, по которым идёт сортировка, а затем сделайте COUNT-запрос на число записей, которые при вашей сортировке окажутся "выше" нужной записи. (т.к. записи не уникальны, то не "выше", а "не ниже")

Comment: Укажите весию сервера.

Comment: Server version: 5.6.34 MySQL Community Server (GPL)